# Scala: Removing key/value pair from list

Tags: list, scala, key, keyvaluepair

Again, I'm stuck with Scala and the key/value pair idea. Again, I want to use Option in some way. This time, I'm stuck on how to remove a pair based on its key, and only that first instance of that key (not all of them). I was attempting to use `filter` and `filterNot` but that removes all the pairs the share the same key. Also, again trying to implement this with just a `List` to keep it semi-simple

Comment: Relying on execution sequence & "first" sounds _procedural_ rather than _functional_, somewhat.

Comment: Since this looks like homework and you're aiming to be as functional as possible while using `List`, I'm going to point you at the `span` function of `List`. Think about how you can decompose the tuple it returns into (head, tail) and what you can do with them.

Comment: @ThomasW Not at all. `List` is an ordered structure, so "first" is well-defined in terms of that structure with no regard to the execution order in which items are added/accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking. It would help if you wrote out the signature of the function you're trying to write.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
def remove[A, B](seq: Seq[(A, B)], key: A): Seq[(A, B)] = 
  seq.indexWhere(_._1 == key) match { 
    case -1 => seq
    case n => seq.patch(n, Nil, 1)
  }

remove(Seq((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5)), 2)
// List((1,2), (3,4), (2,5))

remove(Seq((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5)), 6)
// List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that in. "def remove(key:String):Option[Any]" is what I'm attempting to do

Comment: Um... Where does the List come into play?

Comment: The list is something I'm defining elsewhere. Example List(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3)) where the letters are the "keys" and the numbers the "values".

Answer (score 0):

[Seq has a method called `find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq) that does exactly what you're asking:

```
def find(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): Option[A]

Finds the first element of the sequence satisfying a predicate, if any.

Note: may not terminate for infinite-sized collections.

    p           the predicate used to test elements.

    returns     an option value containing the first element in the
                sequence that satisfies p, or None if none exists.
```

Usage:

```
val list = List(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3))

def remove(key:String): Option[Int] = list.find(_._1 == key)

remove("B")
// Some((B,2))

remove("D")
// None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List(1 -> 'a, 2 -> 'b, 2 -> 'c)

val removal = list find (_._1 == 2)
  // Option[(Int, Symbol)] = Some((2,'b))
val newList = list diff removal.toList
  // List[(Int, Symbol)] = List((1,'a), (2,'c))
```

`diff` will remove only the first instance of each element found in the argument list, not all as `filter` would.